# JPA Map not storing null values

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this map in my @Entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="Subfamily_id")
private Map<Subfamily, AttachedFile> models = new HashMap<>();
```

I can store null values in the "models" map in java (HashMap allows it) but the keys with null values are not persisted by JPA (with Hibernate implementation).

So is JPA breaking the Map contract?
Am I doing something wrong?
Any workaround?

Comment: Better to Check the Null Values while processing the Map Object

Comment: My purpose was to use the keys even if they had null values. The workaround was to store a new list with the keys only, but I'm put off by the handling of null values in JPA: one more counter-intuitive behaviour.